# Create a 3d array from a data frames of x,y,z data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I can think of several dumb ways to do this involving a lot of loops and if statments, but I am wondering if anyone has a smart way.

I have a data frame that has columns of different types of x,y, and z data and I would like to turn that into different 3d arrays. IE

df:

```
    parameter    x    y    z   
1   a            5    -5    478
2   b            5    -5    54
3   c            5    -5    543
4   a            5    0   4
5   b            5    0    25
6   c            5    0    254
7   a            5    5    478
8   b            5    5    54
9   c            5    5    543
10  a            0    -5    4
11  b            0    -5    25
12  c            0    -5    254
```

...etc

so in this case there would be three parameters a,b,and c that are each a 3x3 matrix corresponding to a spatial array:

```
[(-5,5) (0,5) (5,5)
(-5,0 (0,0) (5,0)
(-5,5) (0,-5) (5,-5)]
```

with their respective z values

Diving into it now! Will post my progress, but wondering if there is a wise sage out there!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.. or at least a way that works. I created new data frames for each parameter a,b,c. Then extracted the x,y,x columns from the new data frames and turned them into floats. I sorted the data frame by x and y, turned the data frame into an array and then reshaped the array.

For the x,y component I created an independent array for each.

For example for parameter a:

```
df_a=df.loc[df['parameter']=='a']
df_a=df_a[['x','y','value']].astype(float)
df_a=df_a.sort_values(by=['y','x'],ascending=[False,True])
a_array=df_a['value'].to_numpy()
a_array=a_array.reshape(5,5)
```

and then repeated for all parameters.